# Symbol for end of proof in enumerated proof envioronment

Tags: symbols, theorems, amsthm

With a simple proof environment as follows,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\vspace{-5pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}~\\
            \item First line
            \item Lastline ................\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

the symbol for the end of the proof is on the same line as the last
line of the proof.

If we have an enumeration environment inside the proof environment,
the symbol for the end of the proof only shows up at the next line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\vspace{-5pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}~\\
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First line
        \item Last line ......................
    \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

May the proof environment with an enumeration environment be amended,
so that the symbol for the end of the proof is on the same line as
the last line of the proof?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `\qedhere` macro that's provided by the [amsthm](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package? Can you guess what it does?

Comment: @Mico I see. Unfortunately it does not work in the modified asl documentclass which I am using.

Comment: @Mico I will add an extra line in other proof environments to obtain uniformity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned @Mico in his comment, use `\qedhere`. It will align it with last line in a list, if this line end before right border of text block. If not, than symbol for `\qed` will appear below item text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}~
\item First line
\item \lipsum[1][1-3] And here is the last line \qedhere
    \end{proof}
    
    \begin{proof}~
\item First line
\item \lipsum[66]   \qedhere
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But see my remark in the comment thread above.